# Chrome Storage API String Serializing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, storage

I can't seem to find out why this does not work from reading the Chrome API Reference so I was wondering if anyone here could tell me why
If I save like this:

```
// grab element and save to storage API
    let ELEMENT_DATA = [some string];
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"ELEMENT_NAME": ELEMENT_DATA });  //this is the important bit because of the "" around ELEMENT_NAME.
```

and get like this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["ELEMENT_NAME"], function (result) {
         console.log(result.ELEMENT_NAME.id);
    });
```

There is no problem. Although I need to set and get with a variable name that holds a string like this.

```
for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
 let ELEMENT_NAME = "ELEMENT" + i;   /// = ELEMENT0 and so on... 
 let ELEMENT_DATA = [some string];
chrome.storage.sync.set({ELEMENT_NAME: ELEMENT_DATA });  //PASSING ELEMENT_NAME and not a direct string "" is the issue
}
```

So I thought i could solve this if I JSON.stringify the ELEMENT_NAME variable like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
 let ELEMENT_NAME = "ELEMENT" + i;   /// = ELEMENT0 and so on... 
 let ELEMENT_DATA = [some string];
 let ELEMENT_NAME_STR = JSON.stringify(ELEMENT_NAME); 
chrome.storage.sync.set({ELEMENT_NAME_STR: ELEMENT_DATA }); 
}
```

although this has also proven unsuccessful. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ELEMENT_NAME, ELEMENT_DATA;
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    ELEMENT_NAME = "ELEMENT" + i;   /// = ELEMENT0 and so on... 
    ELEMENT_DATA = 'This is the ' + i + 'th elements';
    obj[ELEMENT_NAME] = ELEMENT_DATA
}
chrome.storage.session.set(obj, _ => {
        chrome.storage.session.get('ELEMENT' + 5, console.log); //retrive one item
        chrome.storage.session.get(['ELEMENT' + 1, 'ELEMENT' + 3], console.log) //retrive more item
        chrome.storage.session.get(null, console.log) //retrive all item
})
```

Comment: how would you go about retrieving the data? 

chrome.storage.sync.get([ELEMENT_NAME], function (result) {
        console.log("ELEMENT: " + result.ELEMENT_NAME); 
    });

? I tried this method and it doesnt seem to work so its either how use .get() which is how i just sent or its something else. what do you think?

Comment: see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Robbi. I went with a similar solution and it did work, although without the .session, I appreciate your help!

Comment: I forgot to replace session to sync 'cause I did a try on my pc.